# Wrap text in R main title of plot exported to pdf file

Tags: r, pdf, plot, rstudio

When I generate plots in RStudio with long 'main' titles, the titles <s>seem to automatically wrap around</s> generally stay within the visible page margins when they are generated by RStudio. But when I use R's pdf() function to export plots to a file, the text <s>wrapping disappears</s> extends beyond the page margins and looks bad. Is there any way to make the plots export with PDF look as good as they look in RStudio? I understand that I can manually insert `\n` characters into the title string, or (I haven't tried this yet) I can play with `strwrap`, but this seems like the kind of functionality that should come out of the box if I just know what switch to flip. Is there an easy way, or just cumbersome, one-off ways?

```
# Demo code for long plot title
plot(density(rnorm(10000,0,1))
     ,main="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor"
)
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't replicate `RStudio` wrapping anything,

Comment: You're right, I should change that. It's not that RStudio is splitting the lines, it's that the title isn't extending beyond the "page" margins in the RStudio window. Maybe I need to configure RStudio to emulate the margins that the pdf export defaults to.

Comment: You still need to provide an example -- I get identical plots (in terms of the title) with `pdf` and the `Rstudio` device.

Comment: I guess I didn't phrase that properly: I didn't mean the RStudio *export* device, I mean the RStudio *viewing window*. It's deceptive to me that the plot looks great in the window and then I export it and it's completely different. Maybe there's a way to get the export to conform to whatever RStudio is doing in that viewing window?

Comment: If you're looking for full consistency between file output and screen output, the `Cairo` package and its functions `CairoX11`, `CairoPDF` etc. might be to your liking.  Won't solve your text wrapping problem though.

Comment: I'll tinker with the Cairo functions and report back, thanks @drammock

Answer (score 1):

### Differences between plot viewing window and file output devices like pdf()

Sometimes plotting in the plot window looks different than in a file output device. In my experience, this is because they have different geometries. Try these...

```
pdf("Desktop/testSmall.pdf",width=4,height=4)
plot(1:10,1:10,main="This is a fairly long plot title with no line breaks")
dev.off()
```

and a larger second plot

```
pdf("Desktop/testLarge.pdf",width=8,height=8)
plot(1:10,1:10,main="This is a fairly long plot title with no line breaks")
dev.off()
```

### Line breaking

The following link suggests this is not a simple problem to solve (but not impossible):

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-June/164458.html

I don't know what "good" means regarding what you see in RStudio, but this splits lines in the main title and centers them.

```
pdf("test.pdf")
plot(1:10,1:10,main=paste("Line one","Line two",sep="\n"))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Under my system, all I need to do is ensure that the orientation is set to `portrait` (whereas landscape is the default)

when you export to pdf, RStudio will give the appropriate pdf height and width given the size of the Rstudio device.